# How to read % Character in Java

Tags: java, character

i have to write a little parsing application, which is rewriting a postscriptfile with some additional infos.

To reach that goal, i am just using a BufferedReader with a FileReader and a FileWriter.
But i am reaching into a problem with an escape character (the % sign).

Java is ignoring this character, the line "%!PS-Adobe-3.0" from the input file will be "!PS-Adobe-3.0" in the String and further the same in the output file.

Do you fellaz have any ideas, how i can do that ... except from reading bytewise :D

Best regards

edit:
Here is the code fragment ... the base file is in encoded in UTF8 :

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args[0]), "UTF-8"));
String line = br.readLine();

Before i testet it with the following:
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

It fails at the same problem -> "%!PS-Adobe-3.0" from the input file became "!PS-Adobe-3.0" in the variable "line"

Comment: Show the code where you're trying to read that. `%` is not special to any of the classes you've listed.

Comment: There's nothing about your now-quoted code that would prevent your reading the `%` correctly. Either the character isn't there and you just think it is (perhaps whatever you're using to look at it uses `%` to indicate something?), or you're doing something else, elsewhere, that strips it out or treats it specially.

Comment: Here are the first lines of the .ps File i try to read into java:
%!PS-Adobe-3.0

%%Creator: CompuSet Version  9.4.0 

%%CreationDate:  5/15/2014   11:11:16 

%%BoundingBox: 0 0 595 842

%%Pages: (atend)

%%DocumentNeededResources: (atend)

%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)


The first % sign at the lines which are begining with "%%" will also be ignored.

Comment: And no ... i am creating the BufferedReader and a the next line i am using br.readLine() ... how should i "manipulate" it otherwise.
Thanks for your great answer

Comment: See above: If those characters are really there, they will be read by the above. What makes you think they aren't being?

Answer (score 1):

The `%` will be read from the file using the code you've quoted. As I've said in comments on the question, if the characters are really there (and I expect they are), the issue is not in that code, but in the code later.

From this comment:

> %!PS-Adobe-3.0 %%Creator: CompuSet Version 9.4.0 %%CreationDate: 5/15/2014 11:11:16 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 595 842 %%Pages: (atend) %%DocumentNeededResources: (atend) %%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend) The first % sign at the lines which are begining with "%%" will also be ignored.

...I'm guessing you're outputting what you're reading using `System.out.printf`, but incorrectly like this:

```
System.out.printf(line); // <=== Wrong
```

The first string you pass into `printf` is a formatting string, and it can placeholders that start with `%`. The `%%` is a special "placeholder" that outputs `%`.

So you're not really seeing the contents of `line`. Try using `print` or `println` instead:

```
System.out.println(line);
```

...or use `printf` correctly:

```
System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
```

`%s` outputs a string unchanged.